# Infinitely many points of spacetime?

Tags: spacetime, resource-recommendations, discrete, lattice-model

Please can someone provided me with academic literature (Journals/Books, titles & links) which discuss the current view on spacetime i.e. that there is not Infinitely many points of spacetime?

Comment: The premise of your question (that the current view on spacetime is that 'there are not infinitely many point of it') is questionable at best. Where did you get this idea?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Relativity

Comment: Is this question about a possible discreteness of space-time?

Comment: Are you familiar with the mathematical concepts of infinity, to wit:  Aleph-null, Aleph-one, etc.?

Comment: Sounds like the OP is interested in lattice field theory on a $n$-torus (or some other topologically exotic space)...also see Jacobson and Foster's "Quantum field theory on a growing lattice" [arXiv:hep-th/0407019](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0407019)

Comment: @pfnuesel Yes, the discreteness of space-time.

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice introduction to Loop Quantum Theory in which both space and time are the result of weaving together fundamental quantum of space itself. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.1330v1.pdf. I am sending you too a page which contains several links and options for the study of this theory. http://cosmicposts.wordpress.com/loop-quantum-gravity/

Enjoy it

Comment: I agree that loop quantum gravity is relevant, but would stress that it's not the most popular theory of quantum gravity. Also, maybe there is something to say about quantum foam?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g.,  http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1330

Answer (score -1):

this is my paper which show that the space in some special curved spacetime is discreete by using one form of generalized uncertainty principle. This paper has been published in {Advances in High Energy Physics}
http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ahep/2013/124543/

Comment: Dear user42958: Welcome to Phys.SE. Are you in any way related to the linked article? For your information, Physics.SE has a [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/582/2451) that it is OK to cite oneself, but it should be stated clearly and explicitly in the answer itself, not in attached links.

Comment: Answers are usually reserved for more detailed responses.  In the future you should leave this type of response as a comment.